# Pygame, border of image get cut while rotating

Tags: python, pygame

I am rotating an image in pygame.

My image is a png and have a lot of free space around it.
[image]
However, when I rotate, I can see the invisible frame around it. 
How to fix this ?
[image]
I am rotating it with this code

```
def rot_center(image, angle):
    """rotate an image while keeping its center and size"""
    orig_rect = image.get_rect()
    rot_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)
    rot_rect = orig_rect.copy()
    rot_rect.center = rot_image.get_rect().center
    rot_image = rot_image.subsurface(rot_rect).copy()
    return rot_image


perso.image = pygame.image.load("sprites/[shadow]main_char_sprite.png")#.convert_alpha()
perso.image = pygame.transform.scale(perso.image, (80,80))
perso.original=perso.image #besoin d'un originial pour faire la rotation
perso.rect = perso.image.get_rect()
perso.rect.x = 200
perso.rect.y = 200
perso.add(perso_group)


counter = 0 #counter define the angle
pygame.key.set_repeat(1,1)

while 1:
    screen.fill(white)
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something
        if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_SPACE:
            counter += 2
            perso.image=rot_center(perso.original, counter) #counter define the angle
            print "rotating now"

    all_group.add(statique_group, zombie_group, perso_group)
    all_group.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

any idea ?

Comment: rotated image is bigger but you use subsurface to cut it and you get  problem. Don't use `subsurface` - keep bigger size.

Comment: what could I use instead of subsurface ? I want to keep rotating it by center...  if found the function rotate center here : http://pygame.org/wiki/RotateCenter?parent=

Comment: use second code on this page - it rotate center but doesn't  keep size so it doesn't cut image.

Comment: Yes I have seen this one but I don't understand why it needs 3 arguments, and then return 2... I have tried implementing it in my code with no success... Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

fixed !

```
perso.image=pygame.transform.rotate(perso.original, angle-90)
perso.rect=perso.image.get_rect(center=perso.rect.center)
```